# Como não repetir postagens em loop do WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou criando uma galeria de *post* como aquela do *globo.com* que aparecem 3 postagens diferentes de uma só vez.

O problema é que ele só pega uma postagem, eu gostaria que os *posts fossem inseridos dentro das `div` sem se repetir.

```
<div class="row">

<?php   $do_not_duplicate = array(); ?>

<?php   
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post',   'posts_per_page' => 1,  'cat' => 1);
$mosaics = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>


<div class="img1">


 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">   <?php the_post_thumbnail('class => img-responsive'); ?>  </a>


</div>
<?php   endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

</div>


<div class="row">

<?php   $do_not_duplicate = array(); ?>
<?php   
 $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post',   'posts_per_page' => 1,  'cat' => 1);
$mosaics = new WP_Query( $args); ?>
<?php   while ($mosaics->have_posts()) : $mosaics->the_post(); ?>
<?php   $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>

<div class="img2 col-md-12">

 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">   <?php the_post_thumbnail('class => img-responsive'); ?>  </a>

</div>


<?php   endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

</div>
```

Como está ficando:

[image: Imagem mostrando o resultado do código acima]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisa fazer um `while`, você pode simplesmente pegar 3 posts de uma terminada categoria, e depois basta utilizar `$posts->the_post();` para capturar o próximo, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$mosaics = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'post', // Tipo da publicação
    'posts_per_page' => 3, // Número de POST
    'cat' => 1             // ID da categoria
]);

if ($mosaics->have_posts()): $mosaics->the_post();
?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="img1">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'img-responsive']); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $mosaics->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="img2 col-md-12">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail', ['class' => 'img-responsive']); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: cara isso e muito simples porem mt importante, resolveu uma penca de gambiarra que eu tinha feito, muito obrigado